How to get a const address from a struct member
I have a template class which requires a pointer to a value:
template<volatile uint32_t* const mReg, uint32_t const BitPos, uint32_t const BitWidth = 1 >
class bField {
public:
    uint32_t Get() const
    {
        constexpr uint32_t mMask = 0xffffffff >> (32 - BitWidth);
        return (*mReg >> BitPos) & mMask;
    }
};

Then, I define a simple struct and a pointer with a const base address of the struct:
typedef struct
{
    volatile uint32_t CR;      
    volatile uint32_t CFGR;    
} RCC_t;
#define RCC_BASE 0x4000000
RCC_t* const mRCC = (RCC_t*)(RCC_BASE);

Finally, I want to instantiate my template class with the address of a struct member:
bField<&mRCC->CR, 25>  PLLRDY_Field;

But unfortunately, I get an error on &mRCC->CR:

expression must have a const value

In my opinion, the pointer to the struct member should be a constant value.
I also made an example in Compiler-Explorer:
https://godbolt.org/z/KT35cPKT5

Can you make a [mre] in a single code blocks and all missing #include so SO users can try to compile without edits and guessing your mind?

What is the actual and underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you need a pointer to a member, and how would this solve your underlying problem?

My underlying goal is accesing register array in my MCU.

Why must this pointer be a template parameter?  Just make mReg a member variable and everything builds.

Fwiw, you can't reinterpret_cast (like you do) and have the result be compile time constant, like you need it to be able to use it as a template parameter.

Make the template parameter uintptr_t and do the cast in the template instead. Or define an actual static struct object and use a linker script to place it at a known address.

"expression must have a const value" -- Which compiler gave you this misleading message? (You did copy-paste the message, right? Attempting to paraphrase an error message you don't understand is a mistake.) Your Compiler Explorer link shows a much more accurate message: "not usable in a constant expression". A constant expression is not the same as something declared with the const keyword (the applicable keyword is constexpr, as mentioned in the note "'mRCC' was not declared 'constexpr'").

According to the hint of could be an AI I found the solution by changing the template parameter to uintptr_t
template<uintptr_t  const mRegAddr, uint32_t const BitPos, uint32_t const BitWidth = 1 >
class bField {
public:
    uint32_t Get() const
    {
        uint32_t *mReg = (uint32_t*)mRegAddr;
        constexpr uint32_t mMask = 0xffffffff >> (32 - BitWidth);
        return (*mReg >> BitPos) & mMask;
    }
};

typedef struct
{
    volatile uint32_t CR;      
    volatile uint32_t CFGR;    
} RCC_t;
#define RCC_BASE 0x4000000
const uintptr_t RegAddr = ((uintptr_t )&((RCC_t *)RCC_BASE)->CR);

bField<RegAddr, 25>  PLLRDY_Field;

